# Read / Write Image in java

Tags: java, string, image

I want to use java to read / write an image and I have got some codes. But I donno how to use the codes, especially in the argument *String...*

Actually in the sample demo that comes together with these codes, the usage is like this:

```
double[] data = Image.load("src/chap08_romsrams/common/lena256.ppm", "../common/lena256.ppm");
```

and this:

```
Image.write(l, "P3", 256, "src/chap08_romsrams/ex1_roms/lena_processed.ppm", "lena_processed.ppm");
```

Let's say that I have an 256*256 image called lena.ppm, which lies in the same folder as the java file, how can I use these functions to read / write the image ...?

Many Thanks !

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Image {
public static double[] load(String... fn) {
    InputStream in = null;

    for (String string : fn) {
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(string);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            /* Empty */
        }
        if (in != null) break;
    }

    if (in == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load input image in Image.load(String...), tried to load image from " + fn);
    }

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(in) );

    try {
        String type = reader.readLine(); // Type
        reader.readLine(); // Comment
        String res = reader.readLine(); // Dimensions
        reader.readLine(); // Intensity range

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+) (\\d+)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(res);
        m.matches();
        Integer width = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        Integer height = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));

        System.err.println(width + "x" + height);

        double[] data = new double[width * height * ((type.equals("P3")) ? 3 : 1)];
        String line;
        int i = 0;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            data[i++] = Integer.parseInt(line);

        reader.close();

        return data;

    } catch(IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public static void write(List<Double> data, String... fn) {
    write(data, "P2", 1024, fn);
}

public static void write(List<Double> data, String type, int width, String... fn) {
    OutputStream out = null;

    for (String string : fn) {
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(string);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            /* Empty */
        }
        if (out != null) break;
    }

    if (out == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to file for output in Image.write(List<Double>, String, int, String...), tried to open " + fn);
    }

    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(out);

    ps.println(type);
    int height = data.size() / (width * ((type.equals("P3") ? 3 : 1))); //1024;
    ps.println("#generated");
    ps.println("" + width + " " + height);
    ps.println("255");
    for(Double d : data)
        ps.println((int)(d.doubleValue()));
}
```

}

Comment: You do indeed have many codes

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try [Java Imaging API](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/index.jsp). Here is the [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/imageio/spec/apps.fm1.html) of how you can do Image IO.
Hope this helps..

Comment: This will add more to your [search](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media)..